# Apache Jmeter JDBC insert test row is not affected in table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jmeter

I made some jdbc test query using Jmeter JDBC test from [JMETER JDBC MENUAL](https://svn.atlassian.com/svn/public/atlassian/vendor/jakarta-jmeter/trunk/docs/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

And I encountered some problem. After I executed below query, I couldn'd found any inserted row from real DB.

Request :

```
[Commit] SELECT @userId := MAX(userId) + 1 FROM userconnection;
SELECT @providerUserId := MAX(providerUserId) + 1 FROM userconnection;
INSERT INTO userconnection(userId, providerId, providerUserId, rank, profileUrl, imageUrl, accessToken, secret)
VALUES (@userId, 'twitter', @providerUserId, 1, '', '', '', '');
```

Sampler result :

```
Thread Name: jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group 1-200
Sample Start: 2014-11-26 17:07:05 KST
Load time: 2
Latency: 2
Size in bytes: 6
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 6
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
Response headers:
com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@1b520e68
SampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/plain
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

Why the result is not affected Real Database?
Are Any rows rollback after executing jemter test?

Comment: Please use Query Type as Update Statement. For more info refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55116782/10514096](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55116782/10514096)

Answer (score 0):

Try using below SQL statement:

*INSERT INTO userconnection
VALUES ((select max(userid) +1 from userconnection), 'twitter', (select max(providerUserId) +1 from userconnection), 1, '', '', '', '');*

Hope this will help.