# Does JDBC request working with Insert query type?

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, prepared-statement

I am trying to run a insert statement which will help me to create user account for my following api calls.
I looked at JMeter JDBC request which has select/update/ect... i don't see insert query type. 
does anyone know how can i run some insert query to create the user for my database?

thanks
L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Update Statement](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) Query type also for inserts

> Update Statement - use this for Inserts and Deletes as well

You may use also Prepared Update Statement type:

> Prepared Update Statement - use this for Inserts and Deletes as well

Answer (score 0):

In [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) terms "insert" equivalent is [`update`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-) therefore you need to choose `Update Statement` from the "Query Type" dropdown:

[image]

You might also find [How to Create Test Data in a Database with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-create-test-data-in-a-database-with-jmeter) useful, it provides more insight and examples.